# How to prevent PostgreSQL full text search parser rewriting symbols to spaces?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, full-text-search

My problem is that the [PL/pgSQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PL/pgSQL) parser treats symbols like '#' or '+' as space symbols (which is OK) hence the queries like 'C++' or 'C#' or 'PL/SQL' are parsed like so:

```
 asciiword | Word, all ASCII | C     | {english_stem}        | english_stem | {c}
 blank     | Space symbols   | #     | {thesaurus_en,simple} | simple       | {#}
```

I'm trying to find a best way to handle this kind of queries. I've been trying to accomplish that by using the thesaurus dictionary, but it doesn't look like it could possibly work.

What I'm thinking of is something that rewrites "C#" to "CSHARP" while writing to the database (since I guess "C#" would be indexed as "C") and something that would do the same while searching.

I could possibly do it on my web application side, but it just doesn't seem right.

How would I handle that or what PL/pgSQL triggers could I possibly use for the approach I'm thinking of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you could write your own parser (in C) but that's probably more effort than you wanted to go to.

You could do something like:

```
to_tsvector('english', my_transformer(document_text)) 
...
to_tsquery('english', my_transformer(query_text))
```

You don't need to transform the actual literal document text, just the tsvector index and the query. You can do this in the index-definition too (but my_transformer needs to be an immutable function).

The question then becomes what the simplest/most efficient way to transform the incoming text is. If you're already using plperl/pltcl then you could probably do some clever regex replacement. If not, try several simpler regex replacements in plpgsql or even plsql. There are always fiddly corner-cases with this sort of thing though, so make sure you test your replacements thoroughly.

Comment: hey, thanks a lot for your answer, custom transformer approach seem to work perfectly so far

Answer (score 1):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP.)*

For future reference, there's a great guide on creating tsearch parser here: http://www.sai.msu.su/~megera/postgres/gist/tsearch/V2/docs/HOWTO-parser-tsearch2.html

Anyway, the solution suggested by Richard works just fine and required much less effort.